# Python - Regular expressions, removing content between two delimiters

Tags: python, regex, replace, delimiter

**Problem;** I am trying to remove the string inbetween and including /* */ for every occurrence inside the input string.

```
input = /* comment */ variable owner; /* comment */
output = variable owner;
```

Currently I have tried doing:

```
output = re.sub("//*[^]+*//", '', input)
output = re.sub("/*[^]+*//", '', input)
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: In Python, `[^]` is an invalid pattern.

Comment: How can i specify all the content in between /*  */ .  I thought this was one way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `[^]` pattern in Python, it is a JavaScript only pattern to match *any* character (as `(?s).` in Python).

However, you may use a better multiline comment matching regex:

```
/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nd2C2R/1). It is an unrolled equivalent of [`(?s)/\*.*?\*/`](https://regex101.com/r/wXx1YO/1) matching `/*`, then any 0+ chars up to the first `*/`.

```
import re
s = '/* comment */ variable owner; /* comment */'
rx = r'/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/'
print(re.sub(rx, '', s))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/lZbpbf)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
output = re.sub("/\*[^\*]+\*/", '', input)
```

Otherwise you can try this one:

```
/\*[^\*]+\*/\s?
```

to get rid of the additional space.